# Length of elements using jQuery is 0

Tags: jquery, list, attributes

I am trying to populate a ul with the following code

```
item = []
item.push('<li title ="head"' + 'id="' + innerValue + '">' + innerKey + " : " + innerValue + '</li>');

alert('<li title ="head"' + 'id="' + innerValue + '">' + innerKey +" : " + innerValue + '</li>');
alert($('[title="head"]').length);
```

The first alert gives me the proper value. 
But the second alert shows a length of 0.

Is there something wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call at the end is searching the DOM, but you've never added those elements to the DOM. If you added them, they'd show up on the search:

```js
var item = [];
var innerValue = "value";
var innerKey = "key";
item.push('<li title ="head"' + 'id="' + innerValue + '">' + innerKey + " : " + innerValue + '</li>');
alert("Before adding to the DOM: " + $('[title="head"]').length);
$("#the-list").append(item[0]);
alert("After adding to the DOM: " + $('[title="head"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="the-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you T.J. You were right. I somehow missed that step.